# Problem with reaching websites on browser after establishing vpn by openconnect

Tags: dns, vpn, openconnect

I used openconnect in terminal for connecting to server. The connection established. I can ping any websites. It looks good for everything. But in Chrome and Firefox I couldn't access to websites. All of the configuration is set to default values, I mean nothing changed. I tried some advise like clear DNS cache. But the problem still exist.